# is there anyway to have images as the nodes in microsoft glee

Tags: image, nodes, microsoft-glee

i see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/saveenr/archive/2008/01/22/visio-leveraging-an-graph-layout-engine-glee-to-automatically-draw-nice-network-diagrams.aspx) but i can't figure out any way to have a node represented as an image and have the text be a label below the node.  Does anyone know if this is possible using Microsoft GLEE?

Comment: Where can the old Microsoft Glee be downloaded (not MSAGL)?

Comment: Deosn't the sample NodesWithImages do this?

Comment: it looks like nodes with image is a MSAGL sample, not a glee sample

Comment: Where do we get Glee? I just found MSAGL for download.

Comment: You can download GLEE @ http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx - it says "Automatic Graph Layout" in the heading, but the file's name is GLEE.msi and it does in fact contain GLEE :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) a bit I came to the conclusion that the author of that blog post (and the author of GLEE/MSAGL itself) used a beta/alpha/development version of the software, which had support for images as nodes.
MSAGL uses `Bitmap`s for loading images and a quick analysis of the GLEE dll's shows that only the `Microsoft.Glee.GraphViewerGdi` assembly depends on `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. Besides that, the `GraphAttr` class would be the most likely place for such a feature and I don't see anything there that could be even remotely (ie. using some weird hack ;)) used for image handling.
Also, notice that the source snippet that the author provided doesn't quite follow the API seen in the version downloadable from MS's site (1.2.0.0).